# Ubuntu tomcat 8 server CPU 100% prolem

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I am working with a ubuntu web server, where I have tomcat 8 and running a web application on tomcat. Recently I have faced some problem with cpu uses 100%. When I restart the tomcat server it is running good, but after one day or a few hour again same problem arise ( 100% cpu use) and that problem make my site slow. When I see the process list with htop command then i see so many process like

```
/opt/java8/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoader
```

The website is a live eCommerce website and average user in every moment is around 100.

The server is a aws ec2 server where a tomcat and a java application inside the tomcat is running. The database (MySql) is in an another aws RDS server.

What can i do in this situation? Please help.

Comment: What is your Instance Type? And Network Bandwidth? What other components you're using in your Production environment of AWS?

Comment: you have many java process running but only one would eat the CPU ? can you kill this one only

Comment: @MurtazaKanchwala My instance type is AWS EC2( m4 x-large). And Bandwidth is unlimited.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri, Yes. You are right. But if i kill the process then tomcat is stopped.

Comment: I think this is more of a Tomcat production optimization problem, rather than EC2. You need to Optimize your Tomcat configuration. You can do one thing. Create a New machine will all your config and optimizations and then create a load balancer and point your Domain to the  ELB(Ofcourse adding both of your EC2 Instance in it). It'll take up a cost for some days but eventually will let you handle your production environment. After that you can terminate that non-optimized instance. And you add more EC2 when required

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Same architecture. And what's more weird is that the CPU goes to 100% usage between 00.00 am and 07.00 am when the app is not being accessed, only some low cron procceses... Did you find the solution?